# Google Play Game Services Detecting Top 3 Players

Tags: java, libgdx, android, google-play-services, leaderboards

I used Google Play Services Leaderboard in my Libgdx game. This is what I want to do; I would like to give awards to the best 3 players in this table. How can I help you?

It automatically connects to the Google Play Services Leaderboard and I can show players' information in the game.

Please help

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I could not try anything because I have no idea how to do it

Answer (score 0):

The [LeaderboardsClient.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/LeaderboardsClient#loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)) method returns a [LeaderBoardScore](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/LeaderboardScore) that you can use to query the `rank` of the current player.